# How to eliminate a python3 deprecation warning for the equality operator?

Tags: python, python-2.7, deprecated

Although the title can be interpreted as three questions, the actual problem is simple to describe. On a Linux system I have python 2.7.3 installed, and want to be warned about python 3 incompatibilities. Therefore, my code snippet (`tester.py`) looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python -3

class MyClass(object):    
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return False
```

When I execute this code snippet (thought to be only to show the problem, not an actual piece of code I am using in my project) as

```
./tester.py
```

I get the following deprecation warning:

```
./tester.py:3: DeprecationWarning: Overriding __eq__ blocks inheritance of __hash__ in 3.x
  class MyClass(object):
```

My question: How do I change this code snippet to get rid of the warning, i.e. to make it compatible to version 3? I want to implement the equality operator in the correct way, not just suppressing the warning or something similar.

Comment: `__eq__` will return False for objects inherited from `object` unless `A is A`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html) page for Python 3.4:

> If a class does not define an `__eq__()` method it should not define a `__hash__()` operation either; if it defines `__eq__()` but not `__hash__()`, its instances will not be usable as items in hashable collections. If a class defines mutable objects and implements an `__eq__()` method, it should not implement `__hash__()`, since the implementation of hashable collections requires that a key’s hash value is immutable (if the object’s hash value changes, it will be in the wrong hash bucket).

Basically, you need to define a `__hash()__` function.

The problem is that for user-defined classes, the `__eq()__` and `__hash()__` functions are automatically defined.

> `x.__hash__()` returns an appropriate value such that `x == y` implies
>   both that `x is y` and `hash(x) == hash(y)`.

If you define just the `__eq()__`, then `__hash()__` is set to return `None`. So you will hit the wall.

The simpler way out if you don't want to bother about implementing the `__hash()__` and you know for certain that your object will never be hashed, you just explicitly declare `__hash__ = None` which takes care of the warning.

Comment: Just a dummy hash function returning essentially nonesense? Or a function that really returns a useable hash value? But whyn do I need to do that, it is not clear from the documentation snippet.

Comment: Again, from the same page:  `__hash__()` should return an integer. The only required property is that objects which compare equal have the same hash value

Comment: Read up the descriptions about the hash and the eq functions - they make it clear.

Comment: I will read the descriptions, but I find it absolutely illogical why I need the hash function anyway. I don't need it, as I define the `__eq__` function. THIS `__eq__` function shall be used to see if two objects are equal, NOT a hash function. But WHEN I also define a hash function, what will be used for an object comparison: the `__eq__` function or the `__hash__` function? I am totally confused...

Comment: From the documentation: `If a class defines mutable objects and implements an __eq__() method, it should not implement __hash__(), since the implementation of hashable collections requires that a key’s hash value is immutable`. So, basically, I do not need a `hash` function, because I define mutable elements. Your answer cannot be correct.

Comment: Yes, I understand that your class will be mutable, and you will never implement a hash for the objects. So you can suppress it by including the info. I have added that to my original answer above.

Answer (score 2):

Alex: python's -3 option is warning you about a potential problem; it doesn't know that you aren't using instances of MyClass in sets or as keys in mappings, so it warns that something that you might have been relying on wouldn't work, if you were.  If you aren't using MyClass that way, just ignore the warning.  It's a dumb tool to help you catch potential problems; in the end, you're expected to be the one with the actual intelligence to work out which warnings actually matter.

If you really care about suppressing the warning - or, indeed, if a class is mutable and you want to make sure it *isn't* used in sets or as the key in any mapping - the simple assignment `__hash__ = None` (as Sudipta pointed out) in the class body shall do that for you.  Since None isn't callable, this makes instances non-hashable.

```
    class MyClass (object):
        def __eq__(self, other): return self is other
        __hash__ = None
```