# Why is __hash__ not inherited when __eq__ is provided?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, hash, python-2.x

The following code works in python 2.7, but fails in python 3.5:

```
class Base(object):
    def __hash__(self):
        return 4

class Derived(Base): pass

class DerivedEquatable(Base):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return False

assert Base.__hash__ is not None
assert Derived.__hash__ is not None
assert DerivedEquatable.__hash__ is not None  # AssertionError in python 3
```

Where is this behaviour change documented?

Comment: FWIW, if you run your code on python2.7 with the `-3` flag, you'll get a `DeprecationWarning`.  Also [this issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue2235) on the tracker has Guido saying "The py3k feature was intentional."...

Comment: Also related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471333/how-to-eliminate-a-python3-deprecation-warning-for-the-equality-operator

Comment: This question is better posed than the other one.  The other one asks "Types that define `__eq__` are unhashable?", to which the answer is "not if they define `__hash__`".

Comment: Direct link to documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__

Comment: @Alexey do you want to suggest an edit to the other question?